# Expectation of the exponential of the sum of Brownian motion and the time it spent above certain threshold

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion and $c\in\mathbb{R}$ be a constant. Calculate the following expectation:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left\{-\int_0^t\mathbb{1}_{\{B_u>c\}}du-\frac{1}{2}t+B_t\right\}\right].$$

Observe that $e^{-\frac{1}{2}t+B_t}$ is a martingale, however, due to the dependence with the term $\int_0^t\mathbb{1}_{\{B_u>c\}}du$ (which is the time of B spent above the barrier $c$), we cannot directly take the advantage of the martingale property. Moreover, the expectation of $\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left\{-\int_0^t\mathbb{1}_{\{B_u>c\}}du\right\}\right]$ is explicit and is given by formula 1.4.3 Borodin and Salminen.

Comment: I noted that (Borodin, Salminen; 1.4.3) has $t = \infty$ and $\mu<0$? Also, note that $e^{-t/2+B_t}$ is a change of measure.

Comment: I'm not sure if we use the same edition, please see the screenshot at https://www.dropbox.com/s/8v8qvx3ntb4e11d/brownian.JPG?dl=0  where $W_0=x$. Would you know how to proceed with the measure change approach?

Comment: I have a second edition source. For your question, try to apply [Girsanov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem).

Comment: Thank you I think I got the hint, which is to identify a transform of B as a Brownian motion under the new measure, then proceed with the formula from Borodin, Salminen.